# converting a string of unicode strings to normal string without single quotes in python

Tags: python, json, unicode-string

This is the json file (file2) in code which is being read:

```
[
    {
        "Id": "cl",
        "description": "Creates",
        "statements": [
            "Sentence1",
            "Sentence2",
            "Sentence3"
        ],
        "parameters": [
            {
                "name": "Id",
                "required": true,
                "description": "Start date for rundate"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

---

This is the python code:

```
file2=sys.argv[2];
loc_file_2=str(sys.argv[2])  ;
open_json_2=open(loc_file_2);
data_2=json.load(open_json_2);

Query_statements_list=data_2[0].get('statements');

json_input_string="";

json_input_string=str(Query_statements_list);

print json_input_string.encode('utf-8');
```

---

output of print:

```
[u'Sentence1', u'Sentence2', u'Sentence3']
```

I desire output to be converted from a unicode string of strings to normal string and without those single quotes and commas,so that i get a single string str

For example:

```
str= Sentence1Sentence2Sentence3
```

Comment: Why do you want to throw away information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `str` on a list, you'll just get the representation of that list in Python syntax.

If you want something else, you should use some string manipulation. For example, you can use `str.join` to produce your desired output:

```
json_input_string = ''.join(Query_statements_list)
```

makes `json_input_string` equal to `Sentence1Sentence2Sentence3`. You can change the string used for joining to get different results. For example,

```
json_input_string = ':'.join(Query_statements_list)
```

would produce `Sentence1:Sentence2:Sentence3`

Comment: Hi nneonneo, if i get the following output                            "Sentence1",FLAG
"Sentence2",FLAG
"Sentence3"FLAG all on a new line after FLAG then how do i get Sentence1FLAGSentence2FLAGSentence3FLAG ?